# How do I block redeployments to Sonatype Nexus OSSRH

Tags: maven, nexus, sonatype

We're deploying our open source libraries to the OSS instance of Sonatype Nexus (https://oss.sonatype.org/) using the nexus-staging-plugin. This works all fine and well. However, since we're using a build server I want to block an accidential re-deployment of an existing artifact id - as this is normally not suppoted by maven. However, the OSSRH happily accepts and updates an existing release. Is there any way to block this and make the build fail?

I know that Nexus can be configured to do that - it is just, that I don't have any permissions to reconfigure the OSSRH instance..

Is there any maven plugin which could check the repo first and fail in first place in case nexus/sonatype does not support this? I looked into the enforcer plugin but there isn't a rule available.

Comment: If you deploy to oss.sonatype.org you will create a staging repository which is unique for every time you are trying to deploy. That's the reason why you can deploy a release version two times...You should simply turn off the "release" option in nexus-staging-plugin.

Comment: But I want to do a release - I just want to block or be notified if s.o. forgot to increment the version. As the staging repo is automatically released by maven and all checks are being executed, I wonder why this essential maven princible is not checked... :-(

Comment: Is the version increment done manually?

Comment: Yep. As a machine can't decide if its major / minor / patch - is there a best practice which is superior to that?

Comment: Why not using release plugin etc. ? or a CI solution to do so which prevents doing things manually.

Answer (score 1):

It is true that there is a staging rule in Nexus which prevents duplicate GAV's being staged, but it is not enabled on https://oss.sonatype.org.  The reason for this is that some users stage artifacts repeatedly (creating multiple staging repositories) and then choose one of them for release based on testing results.

But the server at https://oss.sonatype.org *is* configured so that you cannot release the same artifacts twice.  So if you have two staging repositories that contain the same artifacts you will only be able to release one of them.